# Changing the value of a scalar

Tags: compare, scalar

I'm new to Perl. I'm trying to write a propram that take the entry of 4 numbers and determine the largest and smallest.

This is my program as it stands

```
my $entry1;
my $entry2;
my $entry3;
my $entry4;
my $tempsmall;
my $templarge;

say "Enter first number. \n";
$entry1 = <>;
chomp $entry1;
say "Enter second number. \n";
$entry2 = <>;
if ($entry1 > $entry2)
    {$entry1 = $templarge;
     $entry2 = $tempsmall;
    }
else {
      $entry1 = $tempsmall;
      $entry2 = $templarge;
     }
print "Your first number: $entry1 \n";
print "Your second number: $entry2 \n";
print "Your third number: $entry3 \n";
print "Your fourth number: $entry4 \n";

print "Largest number: $templarge \n";
print "Smallest number: $tempsmall \n";
```

but I get this error message:
   Use of uninitialized value $templarge in concatenation (.) or string at        ./a15compare.pl line 41, <> line 4.
 Largest number:
Use of uninitialized value $tempsmall in concatenation (.) or string at ./a15compare.pl.

What does this error message mean? Any help would be greatly appreciated.